# Why is -2**2 == -4 but math.pow(-2, 2) == 4.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, operators

Why are not these two statements equivalents?

```
>> math.pow(-2,2)
4.0
>> -2 ** 2
-4
```

Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)

Comment: The answer is here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence. `**` has higher precedence than unary negative `-`. Furthermore, `**` is right associative. In practice, right-associativity means, with an example, that `a**b**c = a**(b**c)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of execution of the operators (operator precedence) matters here: with `-2**2`, the exponentiation of 2 to the power 2 is first executed, then the negative sign.

Use parenthesis to obtain the desired result

> (-2)**2 = 4

Answer (score 1):

You can check the precedence from [the Python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html).

> -2**2

calculates as : `-(2**2)` = `-4`.

Answer (score 1):

because the precedence of '-' is behind the precedence of '**', use (-2)**2 to calculate -2 at first